# Bukkit - Compare config string with argument

Tags: string, plugins, arguments, compare, bukkit

i get this wierd bug.
i have this code, which compares the password in the config file with the given argument:

```
if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("login")){
if(getConfig().getString("players."+p.getName()+".password") == args[0]){
p.sendMessage("OK!");
} else {
p.sendMessage("NOT OK!");
}
```

but no matter what, it ouputs "NOT OK!", what am i doing wrong?
ive tried to debug it, to send a message with the given argument and what it sees in the config file.
they were both the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```java
String configValue = config.getString("players."+p.getName()+".password");
if(configValue != null && configValue.equals(args[0]) { // maybe you just need to change the index of args[], depending on if your command looks like /xy <password> or /xy z <password>
    p.sendMessage("OK!");
} else {
    p.sendMessage("NOT OK!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, it had some typing issues but i fixed it!

Comment: You're welcome. For reasons why to use ```.equals()``` instead of ```==``` when it comes to Strings, try out this question: [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: By the way, the most common way of saying thanks here is accepting an answer (ticking the check mark). If you think the answer was useful, you can up-vote it as well (clicking the arrow up)